# MYSQLI fetch array results in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am trying to put mysqli results in alert box. it just show "Already Scanned".

below is the code:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';

$new_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($new_query))
{
    echo 'alert("Already Scanned");
    location.href="javascript:history.back()"';     
}

echo '</script>';
```

how can i put MYSQLI fetch array results in alert box?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have tried. Instead of changing the location, why not do something like: `echo 'alert("id = ' + $row["id"] + '")'`?

Comment: I would like to see the array results and once user press ok button it should go back to previous screen.

Comment: I would like to show full table (ie. name,id,mobile)

Comment: i tried above code it takes me to blank/white page.

Comment: yes it is very necessary ...

Comment: let me tell you...i am creating a cordova barcode scanning app...it scans barcode , shows results in alertbox and go back to previous screen for next barcode scan.

Comment: The problem is that `alert()` freezes the entire thread, and when you press a button in the alert, it immediately executes the code after it. You will not have any luck in displaying the text in the HTML document in this case. The only luck you have will be to edit the `alert()`'s text and then show the data there.

Comment: please give an example...

Comment: you can try with echo 'alert($row);';

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I have understood that this is what you want:

Replace the `echo` command on line `8` with this:

```
echo 'alert("ID: ' + $row["id"] + ', name: ' + $row["name"] + ', mobile: ' + $row["mobile"] + '"); location.href="javascript:history.back()"';
```

This will display all the data you desire to display in the alert box. I understand that this is probably what you want to do right now. Correct me if you wished to do something else.

It isn't the prettiest solution, though.